# Articles in figure captions

Tags: articles

Writing a paper I intend to preface all figures with giving common symbols used in many figures and I'm having trouble using articles. Help me please arrange them.

*"The following symbols are used in _ (1) _ figures:*

[smal picture] *_ (2) _ regulatory region of _ (3) _ gene;*

[smal picture] *_ (4) _ coding region of _ (5) _ gene; possibly several coding sequences under _ (6) _ common promoter (_ (7) _ artificial polycistron unit), or several genes with _ (8) _ identical regulatory regions;*

[smal picture] *_ (9) _ gene expresses if and only if _ (10) _ particles A present; ..."*

[smal picture] *_ (11) _ gene expresses constitutively; in _ (12) _ presence of _ (13) _ particles A, _ (14) _ expression is blocked; ..."*

All the mentioned objects are generalized, not specific.

Looking at papers written by native speakers I see that figure captions begin usually with no articles (cutting off the cases of the plural), sometimes with “the”. The reason is not clear to me. “A” was found rarely and I seem I understand it’s usage.

I guess (2)=(3)=(4)=(5)=(6)=(7)=”a”, (8)=no article because of  generalization.

(1): On the one hand, the sentence applies to all figures, so it suggests an indefinite article. But on the other hand, all this figures are in this specific paper, so “the” – ?

(9), (11): The pictures are not about the gene itself but about the conditions under that it expresses or not. This gene is generalized, so ”a” begs to be used. But we are talking about expression of the very gene that is depicted, so “the” – ?

(10), (13): Again, on the one hand, generalized particles mentioned, so no articles are needed (in the plural), but on the other hand, what is mentioned is depicted and designated as particles of the "A" type, so “the” – ?

(12): I have met both with and withoout “the”; the reasons are not clear.

I seem (14)=”the” since we are talking about the same expression that was mentioned in the same sentence (however as a verb).

I would hope that somebody of native speakers check.